# uisng msvc dll from mingw by code::blocks

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw

I have a simple dll build by c++ msvc2010.  It create a mydll.dll.  (it uses some of windows native dlls so this is a c wrapper.  It has function in it

```
exten "c"
{
    void myfunc(std::vector<std::string> &names)
)
```

Then I use mingw utility pexports.exe and dlltool.exe in mingw\bin folder to convert it.

```
pexports mydll.dll | sed "s/^_//" > mydll.def 

dlltool -U -d mydll.def -l mydll.dll
```

(overwrite the original one. or rename the original one to mydllold.dll.  All dlls are in the same folder of executable of code::blocks program below.)

Then I have a code::blocks project myproc.  The compiler is MinGW's g++.  It links to the mydll.dll in the property->link settings.

The compilation has no error.  But when I run the program 
myproc.exe.  It has run time error:

mydll.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error.

When I use:

```
dlltool -U -d mydll.def -l mydll.a
```

Then rename mydll.dll to mydllold.dll.
And make myproc link settings to mydll.a, it get  error message:

```
The program cannot start because mydll.dll is missing.
```

When I rename mydll.a to mydll.dll, it get same error message:

```
mydll.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error.
```

Note. it does not say mydll.a, instead mydll.dll even the link is to mydll.a.

If I rename mydllold.dll back to mydll.dll.  The error message is:

```
The procedure entry point _myfunc could not be located in the dynamic link library mydll.dll.
```

header file mydll.h:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

extern "C"
{
   MYDLL_API int myfunc(std::vector<std::string>& a);
}
```

mydll.cpp:

```
#include <mydll.h>
extern "C"
{   
    MYDLL_API int myfunc( std::vector<std::string> &a)
    {   
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this as MSVC and g++ use different ABIs.  To share code between MSVC and g++ you could either use COM (which is a fixed ABI definition) or some other IPC method

Comment: Is this link talks about using msvc build dll and use it in MinGW g++ ?    (http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs )  @M.M